# Read a file and sort its contents

Tags: python

I want to read a file, sort text inside the file and overwrite the contents of the file with sorted text.

I have been able to read and sort text, but not sure how to clear contents of the file before writing the sorted text to the file

```
WL01 = 'Test.txt'
with open(WL01,'r+') as WL:
        lines = WL.readlines()
        lines.sort()
        WL.truncate()
        for line in lines:
            print(line, file = WL)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close, just need to return the pointer to the beginning of the file using the seek function, so your code looks like:

```
WL01 = 'Test.txt'
with open(WL01, 'r+') as WL:
   lines = WL.readlines()
   lines.sort()
   WL.seek(0)  
   WL.truncate()  
   for line in lines:
      WL.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `truncate()` method with a size of `0` and after calling `truncate(0)`, the file pointer will be at the end of the file, so it is necessary to use the `seek(0)` method to move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file before writing the sorted text!

check this out:

```
WL01 = 'Test.txt'
with open(WL01, 'r+') as WL:
    lines = WL.readlines()
    lines.sort()
    WL.truncate(0) #clear the contents of the file!!!
    WL.seek(0)  #move the file pointer to the beginning of the file
    for line in lines:
        WL.write(line)
```

Comment: Please link to the documentation so we can read about that.

Comment: And I just tried it, it [didn't work](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lZHPbsIwDMa1a5_C1Q5pBKvgNiHxBj0i9ZxljhqpiivHqPAsXLjAQ-1plrRsCIkLvvnP95M_-3QdjtJROJ8ve3Efnz9v1DarNWxB7TBKLQdRRTF66YAGDFVuLkGNSoOJ0DabAlI4YrDgAyhH9GVYzeUcA_sglV2C8z1u20Y_ofEjbZb0Pkoa0E8Fi0dF7wPGtHPb1Izme0orfW_VkVhuhTQjvA_WCFYrDe-2R8MgHYKlIBgkArkpzxuXZfnvMKOyyQl5d5iAI_tEy_XX7c13v53_7w2_).